# Console window exits when debugging

Tags: c#

I'm trying to run a program like a for loop. But when it starts debugging the console window disappears immediately. How do I stop this. I need something like press any key to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a statement like

```
Console.Read()
```

That way, the console will remain until you press a key.

For more information, read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Write `Console.ReadLine()` or `Console.Read()` or `Console.ReadKey()` at the end of your program.

It will make your screen wait for your key press in order to exit.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention any example code. This is my example code. Program waits for pressing a key

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that pressing the Ctrl + F5 key makes the console stay.